# Deployment of a Swing application that uses a database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have created a Java Swing application with database in NetBeans IDE. I have a database created directly in NetBeans. How do I arrange that this application will be installed to run outside NetBeans IDE? For example in Windows. When I have applications without database, it is easy; but the database I do not know.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: [tag:java-web-start] is a good deployment option.

Comment: How are you doing the installation? Manually copying and pasting? Using some kind of framework?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install a database such as:

- mysql, microsoft sql, sqlite, etc.

You can also get portable versions of these that only require an unzip and run (e.g. mysql in xampp).

You will need to create a script (either in your program or do it by hand) to create the necessary schema, and tables that are needed.

Your application must have the same credentials for both your database but also within your requests from java.

If your doing the installation by hand you usually do all the above by hand.
The database need not be on the same computer but can be on the same network or also on the internet - but it will have to be somewhere unless your using something portable like sqllite.

If your creating an automated install script you should define that in your question.